# Using One Page Login/Registration with Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

So, I have Witten some code in flutter. here I asking the phone number to generate OTP and after passing the OTP it successfully login. but here I need some changes. When even I submitted the OTP then its check the number is already in the firebase phone authentication console. if its already been their it will just show me the home page. otherwise if the number is not exist then it goes to a UserInformation page where user need to give some simple information then after continue it will show the home page. in a sense I need a one page login registration panel by using only phone number.
here is my flutter code.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pinput.dart';

import '../utils/route.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUpPage> createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  // bool _obscureText = true;
  String countryCode = "+880";
  String phoneNumber = "";
  String otpCode = "";
  String phoneVerificationId = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  

  signUp(String phoneNumber) async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
        phoneVerificationId = verificationId;
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
    );
  }

  final defaultPinTheme = PinTheme(
    width: 56,
    height: 56,
    textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 60, 87, 1),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFF1818B4)),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final focusedPinTheme = defaultPinTheme.copyDecorationWith(
      border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFF1818B4)),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    );
    final submittedPinTheme = defaultPinTheme.copyWith(
      decoration: defaultPinTheme.decoration?.copyWith(
        color: Color.fromRGBO(234, 239, 243, 1),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1818B4),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Column(children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 70.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/we_serve.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              'WHERE SERVICE MEETS EXCELLENCE',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, bottom: 10),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Please Enter Your Mobile Number",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    enabled: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                      hintText: "  +880",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 64, 63, 63),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 5),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 7,
                  child: TextField(
                    // controller: _phoneController,
                    onChanged: (value) => {
                      phoneNumber = countryCode + value,
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        // labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                        hintText: "Mobile Number",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              signUp(phoneNumber);
              showDialog(
                barrierColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.7),
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    elevation: 8,
                    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.white),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                    title: Container(
                      color: Color(0xFF1818B4),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Text('Verification Code'),
                      )),
                    ),
                    content: Container(
                      height: 120,
                      child: Form(
                        // key: _formkey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            Center(
                                child: Text("Please Enter Your 6-digit OTP")),
                            SizedBox(height: 20),
                            Pinput(
                              defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
                              focusedPinTheme: focusedPinTheme,
                              submittedPinTheme: submittedPinTheme,
                              pinputAutovalidateMode:
                                  PinputAutovalidateMode.onSubmit,
                              length: 6,
                              showCursor: true,
                              onChanged: (value) => {
                                otpCode = value,
                              },
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    actions: [
                      Center(
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            try {
                              final currentUser =
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

                              print(currentUser?.uid);

                              PhoneAuthCredential credential =
                                  PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                                      verificationId: phoneVerificationId,
                                      smsCode: otpCode);
                              print(credential);
                              await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
                            } catch (e) {
                              print("Wrong OTP");
                            }
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFE001),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 40, right: 40, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                            child: Text(
                              'Confirm',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                  // color: Color(0xFF1818B4),
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFE001),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 70, right: 70, top: 10, bottom: 10),
              child: Text(
                'Continue',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    // color: Color(0xFF1818B4),
                    color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                // Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
              },
              child: Text(
                'Contact Us',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  color: Color(0xFF808080),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have completed the phone verification system successfully. Now want to separate mechanism for new user and old user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an opinion for your requirement. I give you a suggestion according to Firebase.

When Otp verification completed then you can check a one condition. Where you can use Firebase Firestore or Realtime database to check user number exists or not. If user number not exist then user will be redirected to Register flow and user once fill the details and submit the details at that time store user phonenumber into Firebase database.

And every after Otp verification complete check condition if user phone exists or not according to that make Routing.

If you use Firebase Firestore so you can achieve it like this:

You can create a table for **users:**

For check user exist or not so you can do it like this:

```
Future<bool> isUserExist(String phoneNumber) async {
    final usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final querySnapshot = await usersCollection
        .where('phoneNumber', isEqualTo: phoneNumber)
        .get();

    return querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty;
  }
```

User routing after Otp verification:

```
routeUser(phoneNumber) async {
    final userExists = await isUserExist(phoneNumber);

    if (userExists) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserInformationPage()),
      );
    }
  }
```

For creating user while Register user info submission:

```
Future<void> createUser(String phoneNumber) async {
    final usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    // Set the document with the user phone number as the ID
    await usersCollection.doc(phoneNumber).set({
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
      // If need to store others data so you can also store them
    });
  }
```

Flow:
[image]

Comment: Can you please guid me how can i store the phone number and user uid to the collection when register for a new number. I am trying to fix the issue depending on your oponion but couldn't understand how to store the data

Comment: First of all if you find answer helpful then mark it verified for other devs

Comment: Did you store user info in Backend or Firebase?